# Unable to impose textview within UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I would like to allow users to input multiple lines of text. Im using UIAlertController to do so. Following is my code that I use.

```
    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Remarks"
                                  message:@"Please enter the remarks:"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                   UITextField *email = alert.textFields.firstObject;
                                                   NSLog(@"%@",email.text);

                                                   if (![email.text isEqualToString:@""])
                                                   {
                                                   }
                                                   else
                                                   {
                                                       [self showMessage:@"Remark is mandatory" withTitle:@"Remarks!"];

                                                   }

                                               }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                   }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];


    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Enter the remarks";
    }];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem is,

1. The text field within the UIAlertController controller doesnt support multi like texts. How can I replace the textfield with textview?
2. Is there any other alternative through which I can get the input via textview by implementing pop up as in UIAlertController?

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420080/multiline-editable-text-uitextview-inside-uialertcontroller

Comment: i have checked it but im using objective c and not swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom iOS AlertView.This helped me.

https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview